# How to change the style of the analogue clock in XFce?

Tags: xfce, theme

The XFce4 clock applet has an option to display an analogue clock. I found that this clock is not easy to read and the appearance does not match the rest of the desktop. Is there any way to configure the appearance of this clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. In `Xfce 4.10` you may only enable `Display seconds`. As for matching the rest of the desktop, here I use `Darklooks` and the clock appropriately changes colors to conform to the theme; so I assume that the appearance that you have is as good as it gets.